# CanDeactivateGuard doesn't work with confirmation subscription

Tags: angular, forms, candeactivate

I need to create canDeactiovateGuard to prevent user losing form data when trying to leave form page. 
This code below doesn't work since return canDeactivate works before canDeactivate = confirmed. I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<Component> {

  canDeactivate(component: Component): boolean {
    let canDeactivate: boolean;
    if (component.formValueChanged) {
        component.confirmService.confirm("You have unsaved data. Are you sure?")
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe((confirmed: boolean) => {
                canDeactivate = confirmed;
            });
    } else {
        canDeactivate = true;
    }
    return canDeactivate;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try instead to return an `Observable<boolean>`. This can be done via operators such as RxJS map. Either way, in guards such as CanDeactivate or CanActivate, basically you would never use `subscribe()` as you can't return anything from within a `subscribe()` and instead return `Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree`:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<Component> {

  canDeactivate(component: Component): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    if (component.formValueChanged) {
        // Return the observable instead of the subscription
        return component.confirmService.confirm("You have unsaved data. Are you sure?")
            .pipe(first())
            // You may be able to remove map() assuming confirm() always returns Observable<boolean>
            .map((confirmed: boolean) => confirmed);
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Return the observable instead of the subscription - 
Yes, this works! Thank you!